# What is causing the CPU burst capacity to be very high on lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have a basic lightsail instance 1 GB RAM, 1 vCPU, 40 GB SSD with very small WP website with barely 10 visitors. My CPU burst capacity is always very high.

What could be the reason for the high spike?

Comment: Burst capacity, or burst usage? If the capacity is high, that would be expected, since you aren't using it, so the capacity is there. If the usage is high, then you need to run something like `top` on the server to see what is using the CPU.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @MarkB Community,
I've attached a reference screenshot from the lightsail
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h959cjdaGp-hHI9fxvdCpA1m4ubNNdR6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

From that chart, you are barely using any CPU. That metric (burst capacity) is a measure of how much *potential* CPU burst capacity you have available. If it is staying at 100% then it means you are using very little CPU and you can safely burst the CPU usage some.

Notice the two alert lines on the chart (denoted by "1" and "2") at 75% and 50% burst capacity. Those alerts will trigger when you have less than that that amount of burst capacity available.

I suggest reading [the official documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-viewing-instance-burst-capacity) on Lightsail CPU Burst Capacity.

Comment: what should I do when the CPU Burst Capacity < 30%? I cannot access to my server..

Comment: @Amzar that's a completely separate question. Please ask a separate question on here instead of tacking on your issue to someone else's question.